# HTML5 Video tag suddenly stopped working on Safari desktop

Tags: html, safari, html5-video, mime-types

I have read through and tried suggested solutions on many other similar questions to this one, but nothing is working. When I initially deployed this code a few months ago, it was working on all browsers, mobile and desktop. Now, suddenly, there's no video rendering on Safari (desktop only—it still works on mobile).

```
<video muted
       playsinline
       disablepictureinpicture
       loop
       class="video"
       preload="metadata">
  <source src="assets/videos/cl.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  <source src="assets/videos/cl.mov" type="video/mov"/>
  <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>
```

The unsupported message doesn't render, but no video renders either. Did something change with Safari recently? What else do I need to get this working again?

I have tried:

1. re-encoding the mp4 file with:

```
ffmpeg -i cl.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -movflags faststart cl-encoded.mp4
```

2. adding the `controls` attribute
3. adding multiple source types

Comment: Note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Thanks @Rob I didn't know that. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work on Safari.

Comment: Maybe this is a Safari bug? https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690523

Answer (score 0):

```
<video class="video-background" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
```

It works when you include a playinline word and add the source file

Comment: Both of those are included in my code above.